# Many-To-Many updating relationships MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am trying to update relationships between a many-to-many relationship.

I have this configuration:

```
this.HasMany(student => student.Courses)
            .WithMany(course => course.Students)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("T_Student_Course");
                mc.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
                mc.MapRightKey("CourseId");
            });
```

I have a MultiSelectList that I am choosing courses from to add to a student, and in the code on the Action I have this:

```
student.Courses = new List<Course>();

foreach (var courseId in SelectedCourses)
{
    Course course = _db.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == courseId);

    student.Courses.Add(course);
}

_db.SaveEntity(student);
```

This will not remove courses that were deselected.  It leaves them in the mapping table.  How do I get it to remove Course_1 and Course_2 and add a new Course_3?  Or, remove Course_1 and leave Course_2 which was previously selected?

Comment: Have you tried taking out the student.Courses = new List<Course>(); line and just calling student.Courses.Remove(course); to remove the courses that aren't selected?  If you want to do this quick, call student.Courses.Clear(), then add selected courses, then call SaveEntity.

Comment: (You may have to call Clear, SaveEntity, Add, then SaveEntity again; however, I would think the entity tracking would handle that.)